# background image not showing up because there's something wrong with my CSS background

Tags: css

my regular css

```
background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(221, 15, 0, 0.397),
        rgba(24, 0, 0, 0.384)
    ),
    url('./img/hot.svg');
```

when inspecting hot.svg has a random number in it

```
background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(221, 15, 0, 0.397), rgba(24, 0, 0, 0.384) ), url(/static/media/hot.6aea5233.svg);
```

this is a css file under React so I'm not sure if it's related to react.

Comment: try to check _/static/media/hot.6aea5233.svg_ **can be reached**, and change  ```url(/static/media/hot.6aea5233.svg);``` to ```url('./static/media/hot.6aea5233.svg');```

Comment: Is fix the issue ?

Comment: Are you using webpack or anything similar?

Comment: not sure why but after sleeping it overnight it suddenly fixed itself. Thank you for all the help